# Get Used Range of Filtered ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the visible cells of a filtered table to another sheet.

I am getting an error that `Range.Address` is an invalid qualifier, although I read, this is how you must refer to a list object range.

```
Sub TestRun()
    Dim strng As Range
    Dim lo_b1 As ListObject

    Set lo_b1 = x_bf1.ListObjects(1)
    Set strng = ThisWorkbook.Names("co_st").RefersToRange

    lo_b1.Range.Address.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy strng

End Sub
```

Comment: What error happens if you just do `lo_b1.SpecialCells(...).Copy` or `lo_b1.Range.SpecialCells(...).Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny example.  Starting with a ListObject in Sheet1:

[image]

This will apply a filter and copy the visible rows elsewhere:

```
Sub KopyTab()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range

    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="mike"
    rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

The result:

[image]